# How to resolve the "Could not initialize class org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor"?

Tags: java, scala, cassandra

I m just reading csv file in scala code and formatted as cassandra row after I want to print the cassandra row the getting this error:

input.txt

```
customer_1,1,2015-10-10 00:00:00+0000,0,2015-10-10 00:00:00+0000,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
customer_1,2,2015-10-10 00:00:00+0000,0,2015-10-10 00:00:00+0000,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
```

my code for reading is here:

```
def inputReader(inputfile: String) = {
 val dataFile = getClass.getResource(inputfile).getFile

  val baseRDD: RDD[CassandraRow] = sc.textFile(dataFile).map { line =>
  val reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line))
  val row = reader.readNext()
  val bArray: Array[Byte] = Try(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(row(5).trim)).getOrElse(null)
  new CassandraRow(Array("cusid", "appid", "weekdate", "bucket", "eventtime", "data"),
    Array(row(0).trim, row(1).trim, row(2).trim, row(3).trim, row(4).trim, bArray))
    }

  baseRDD.take(5).foreach(println)
  baseRDD
 }
}
```

I'm getting error on "baseRDD.take(5).foreach(println)"
my error is:

```
Loading settings from file:/etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
[2016-02-24 20:13:50,620] INFO  o.a.c.c.YamlConfigurationLoader [15b55e14-9ee3-463f-9da0-d39e704ef6b8] [akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/demeter] - Node configuration:[authenticator=PasswordAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_snapshot=true; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=64; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=demeter-sharada; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_directory=/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_writes=32; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[/data/cassandra]; disk_failure_policy=stop; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; endpoint_snitch=com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; incremental_backups=false; initial_token=null; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_compression=all; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=10.29.23.136; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; memtable_cleanup_threshold=0.9; native_transport_port=9042; num_tokens=256; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=10.29.23.136; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_port=9160; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=/var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches; seed_provider=[{class_name=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider, parameters=[{seeds=10.29.23.136}]}]; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=true; storage_port=7000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; write_request_timeout_in_ms=10000]

  [2016-02-24 20:13:50,935] INFO  o.a.c.c.DatabaseDescriptor [15b55e14-9ee3-463f-9da0-d39e704ef6b8] [akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/demeter] - DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mma [2016-02-24 20:13:50,968] INFO  o.a.c.c.DatabaseDescriptor [15b55e14-9ee3-463f-9da0-d39e704ef6b8] [akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/demeter] - Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 245MB

    [2016-02-24 20:13:50,968] INFO  o.a.c.c.DatabaseDescriptor [15b55e14-9ee3-463f-9da0-d39e704ef6b8] [akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/demeter] - Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 245MB
 [2016-02-24 20:13:51,376] ERROR o.a.c.c.DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor [15b55e14-9ee3-463f-9da0-d39e704ef6b8] [akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/demeter] - Error in ThreadPoolExecutor
 **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor**
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JVMStabilityInspector.inspectThrowable(JVMStabilityInspector.java:58) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.969.jar:0.6.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$UncomplainingRunnable.run(DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:122) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.969.jar:2.1.11.969]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
```

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor

Maybe your Cassandra install is corrupted or your CLASSPATH setting is missing cassandra jars