# How do I start the CDC agent in a Stargate container?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-astra, stargate-oss

I'm trying to build an integration test for [Datastax CDC](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra/cdc-for-astra-db). I'm trying to follow the directions [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cdc-for-cassandra/docs/2.2.9/install.html) to create a containerized Stargate instance running the [CDC Java agent](https://github.com/datastax/cdc-apache-cassandra). I'm using the following docker file:

```
FROM stargateio/coordinator-4_0:v2

ENV CLUSTER_NAME="test"
ENV CLUSTER_VERSION="4.0"
ENV DEVELOPER_MODE="true"
ENV ENABLE_AUTH="true"

RUN (curl -L https://github.com/datastax/cdc-apache-cassandra/releases/download/v2.2.9/agent-c4-2.2.9-all.jar --output agent-c4-2.2.9-all.jar)
ENV JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:agent-c4-2.2.9-all.jar"
```

I'm using `JAVA_OPTS` because `JVM_EXTRA_OPTS` appears to have no effect. Stargate inserts these into the [start command](https://github.com/stargate/stargate/blob/e25166320bcce062324118652e0fba6f454b63cb/coordinator/starctl#L123). I'm getting this error:

```
Using environment for config
2023-05-18T20:53:28.708821506Z Running java -server -javaagent:agent-c4-2.2.9-all.jar -Dcassandra.libjemalloc=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.2 -Dstargate.libdir=./stargate-lib -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar ./stargate-lib/stargate-starter-2.0.13.jar --cluster-name test --cluster-version 4.0 --listen 172.17.0.2 --enable-auth --developer-mode
2023-05-18T20:53:28.771770673Z SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
2023-05-18T20:53:28.771806548Z SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
2023-05-18T20:53:28.771810090Z SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2023-05-18T20:53:28.773310423Z Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2023-05-18T20:53:28.773331381Z  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2023-05-18T20:53:28.773333715Z  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2023-05-18T20:53:28.773336006Z  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2023-05-18T20:53:28.773337756Z  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2023-05-18T20:53:28.773339298Z  at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
2023-05-18T20:53:28.773341298Z  at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
2023-05-18T20:53:28.773343131Z Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cassandra/config/DatabaseDescriptor
2023-05-18T20:53:28.773344881Z  at com.datastax.oss.cdc.agent.Agent.main(Agent.java:49)
2023-05-18T20:53:28.773346631Z  at com.datastax.oss.cdc.agent.Agent.premain(Agent.java:31)
2023-05-18T20:53:28.773348715Z  ... 6 more
2023-05-18T20:53:28.773350340Z Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor
2023-05-18T20:53:28.773352090Z  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
2023-05-18T20:53:28.773353798Z  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
2023-05-18T20:53:28.773355465Z  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
2023-05-18T20:53:28.773357131Z  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
2023-05-18T20:53:28.773358756Z  ... 8 more
2023-05-18T20:53:28.773360340Z FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
```

I've tried downloading the Cassandra `.jar` files and adding them to the classpath (as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609078/how-to-resolve-the-could-not-initialize-class-org-apache-cassandra-config-datab)) to no avail. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Hey, mate! I just wanted to acknowledge your question. We've reached out to the Stargate devs and will post an update/answer as soon as we have something. Cheers!

Comment: Great question, Spencer!  I'm interested to see how this one turns out.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like we've attempted this before so we don't have a working example to show you.

We are looking into it and will attempt to get it to work in the next few days. I will post an update once I have something to report. Cheers!

**[UPDATE]** CDC integration with Stargate is not supported yet. I've logged a feature request on your behalf (ref [#2587](https://github.com/stargate/stargate/issues/2587)) in an attempt to get it on the roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Java stack trace above, the likely reason you are encountering the exception is because the jar file containing the Java agent code (`agent-c4-2.2.9-all.jar`) is missing Apache Cassandra dependencies.

Here are some possible solutions:

1. Use an agent jar file that has all its dependencies bundled into it.
2. Or, specify the missing dependencies in the classpath.

The JDK documentation for [insrumentation](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/panama/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) has a section on how agent classes are loaded and also a section on how agent jar files can specify their `Boot-Class-Path` for loading dependencies.

Hope that helps.

Cheers